# I can run my emulator(Android studio) but in emulator screen I can't find the app I made

Tags: android, android-studio

I make a project but when I run the emulator I can't find my app in anywhere; in menu in main page?
here is the photo:

[image]

and when I try to build here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the LogCat error Message in order to help you ?

Comment: Did you see the logs for details?

Comment: Your app is not built at all, how do you expect to see it on screen. Please post your logcat message for more clarity.

Comment: 18:11:11 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
18:11:34 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 22s 735ms is that the log?

Answer (score -1):

i think you have included some image and that's causing the error.

Comment: yes  I added some images but why is it happening and what should i do?

Comment: Try to run the project without including the images and then see. Some image formats are not supported maybe that's the reason.

Comment: I even try that in new project(without images) but still i can't build apk

Comment: Can you show the code that you wrote for your project?

Comment: sure but from mediafire or ?